# Is it possible to secure an input that can be both readonly or not in angular?

Tags: angularjs, forms, security, angularjs-directive, readonly

#### Introduction

I have inputs in a form with variables assigned to an **ng-model** attribute.
There are several buttons with different actions that can submit the form with different results in the end. For that reason, I added the novalidate attribute.

Here is a sample of what the code looks like :

```
<form ng-submit="submitFunc()" novalidate>
  <input type="text" ng-model="good.category" ng-readonly="good.id"/>
  ...
  <button ng-click="action1()" ng-disabled="missingInfo()">save</button>
  <button ng-click="action2()" ng-disabled="!good.info1">'loose' save</button>
  <button ng-click="delete()" ng-if="good.id" type="button">delete</button>
  <button ng-click="action3()" ng-if="isSpecial">Add caracteristic</button>
```

I use this form to **register a good** from scratch, but i can also **modify** an existing one.

If I am **creating** the good, the input containing the category of the object will be **mandatory**.
But if I am **modifying** it, the category should be **unchangeable**.

#### Make it secure

I already use a "**readonly**" (EDIT: ng-readonly="good.id") attribute to make it impossible to modify the category , but my question is :

> How do you make this input secure, regarding possible manipulation of the html ?

By secure I mean, making it impossible to give a new category to an existing object.

> EDIT: Considering the answer of Quertiy: 
>   In which extent, the ng-readonly directive makes it more secure than a simple readonly attribute ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you make this input secure, regarding possible manipulation of the html ?

The only way to do application secure is to validate data on server-side.
Just drop `category` if `id` is presented.

> But if I am modifying it, the category should be unchangeable for good.

`ng-required` and `ng-disabled` accept boolean as parameter. Use it somehow like that:

```
<input ng-model="good.category" ng-disabled="good.id" ng-requred="!good.id">
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. --- In fact i can't use ng-required because I already have novalidate attribute on the form itself. --- I have many submit buttons each with a different behaviour you see. --- I think you confirmed what I thought. --- I should add more verifications in the controller to delete not wanted informations ?

Comment: @RomainVincent, `novalidate` doesn't affect angular validators.

Comment: Do you mean that if I put an ng-required, it is doing more than simply adding a required if expression equals to true ?

Comment: @RomainVincent, yes, of couse. Angular validation differs from native browser validation.